# Oracle SQL function to return a value one or many

Tags: sql, oracle

**Table** Subject_student_relation

- 1) student_name/id
- 2) subject_name
- 3) course_type (own/shared)

**View** Subject_info

- 1) student_name
- 2) course_status (one/many)

I need a function to pass the student name and I need to check for all subjects associated with it. If any course type is shared for that subject, then return many; else, return one.

I have done with

With and sum case course type is shared > 1, but I'm getting for all subjects it's one or many. How to evaluate for the student?

Count alone is not working because for same student say Michael for course mathematics two records are present one as own and other as ranker a special entry to denote he is ranker.

Subject info is having Michael this subjects are math science for math he is own and for science he is own too but for math Elizabeth is shared then the course status is shared how to achieve this.

[image]

[image]

I'm doing for course I need this same logic for student
[image]

Comment: Please post the actual code of your function. Are you accepting student name as an in parameter ?

Comment: Actual tables and data will make this a lot easier to answer. By the way, **Michael** won't be happy that you misspelled his name ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
function f_student (par_student_name in varchar2) 
  return varchar2
is
  l_cnt number;  -- number of "shared" courses
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from subject_student_relation r join subject_info i on i.student_name = r.student_name
  where r.student_name = par_student_name
    and r.course_type = 'shared';

  return case when l_cnt > 0 then 'many'
              else 'one'
         end;
end;
```

It is unusual to distinugish people by their names (at least, in IT area, not in everyday usage), because there are people who have the same name. What if there are two students named "Michael Jackson" - how will you know which one's subjects you're looking at? I guess you'd need some kind of an ID.

Comment: The same course math will be own for student Michael but will be shared for Elizabeth. Then for Micheal it should return shared too. Will the above code words that way

Comment: I don't know. Try it and you tell me. Also, consider editing your original message (question) and provide sample data and expected result. It is easier to work that way.